# How to add multiple items to the DefaultComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, defaulttablemodel

I have the following code but I don't know how to add all of the items to my combobox.

```
DefaultTableModel rs = MyDB.DataTable("SELECT `Activity` FROM `transactions` WHERE `Group` = '" + Gname.getText()+ "' OR `Group` = 'ALL'");

DefaultComboBoxModel dmc = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

dmc.addElement("");

if (rs.getRowCount() > 0) {
    dmc.addElement(rs.getValueAt(0,0).toString());
}

cboItem.setModel(dmc);
```

It only adds one item to my `DefaultTableModel`, how can I add all of them?

Comment: You want to add values to `DefaultComboBoxModel ` or `DefaultTableModel` ?

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See [*Using a Combo Box as an Editor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox).

Comment: add items in my combox from table @Apurv

Comment: the list of rs are in MySQL, so when I call the items I want I Will put it all in the ITEMS of my combobox  @Apurv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of `DefaultComboBoxModel` takes `Object[]`. You can first iterate over the `rs` values prepare an array (or list) and then pass this array to `DefaultComboBoxModel` constructor. Like this ...

```
DefaultTableModel rs = MyDB.DataTable("SELECT `Activity` FROM `transactions` WHERE `Group` = '" + Gname.getText()+ "' OR `Group` = 'ALL'");
int columnCount = rs.getColumnCount();
int rowCount = rs.getRowCount();

List <Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex ++){
    for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++){
         Object value = rs.getValueAt(rowIndex , columnIndex );
         values.add(value);
    }
}
DefaultComboBoxModel dmc = new DefaultComboBoxModel(values.toArray());
```

Comment: non-static method getValueAt(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: With `defaultTableModel` I mean object of `DefaultTableModel` which in your case is `rs`

Comment: the list of `rs` are in MySQL, so when I call the items I want I Will put it all in the ITEMS of my combobox @Apurv

Comment: type List does not take parameters @Apurv `List <Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Comment: What do you mean by this ?

Comment: There is no issue with the code I posted. `List <Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();` works fine!

Comment: `type List does not take parameters` thats the error it red line in my netbeans

Comment: It's common courtesy to "accept" an answer here on SO. Feel free to check the answer you feel that solves your problem.