# Unable to change IntelliJ GUI form components through Bean class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to change the elements of a Combobox that was created through a GUI form.

It generates:

```
private JComboBox<String> example;
```

But if I try and do:

```
example = new JComboBox<>(...);
```

, nothing occurs.
It simply shows the GUI as I set it on the form with no modification.

How am I to modify components while using IntelliJ's GUI form, then?

Comment: The component is initialized by the code generated by the GUI designer, you must not override the initialization. There is `custom create` option available in case you want to initialize the components yourself, otherwise populate the values with `addItem` method.

Comment: Is there a way of adding multiple items with one invocation or must I invoke `addItem` multiple times?

Comment: You can either add them in a loop with `addItem` or [add them to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491211/104891) and set a model to the existing JComboBox.